# Distance for No Quantum Effects Between Two Wires

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Two wire traces on a substrate are separated by a distance d. Each wire carries a current. The mean energy of the electrons in the wires is E. Estimate the minimum distance that must exist between the two wires such that quantum effects are negligible.

Not really sure how to consider this question. What would be a good starting point?

Comment: That's actually quite mysterious. Is that all the information you're given? Is this part of a larger assignment?

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret 'quantum effects' as electrons jumping from one wires to the other, that happens when the separation $d$ is of the same order of magnitude of the electrons wavelength - that depends on their energy $E$

Comment: nice answer. superb